# Union of functions is not callable even with parameters that meet each function's constraints

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to compile this Typescript snippet:

```
function foo(v: string) { return 'foo'; }
function bar(v: string | number) { return 'bar'; }

const notCallable: typeof foo | typeof bar = function() {} as any;

// Fails type check, even though all the unioned functions accept string.
notCallable('a');
```

The compiler infers the type of `notCallable` as `((v: string) => string) | ((v: string | number) => string)`, which looks fine, but is not considered callable:

> Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '((v: string) => string) | ((v: string | number) => string)' has no compatible call signatures.

Note that if the parameter lists match, it works fine, even if the return types differ.

```
function foo(v: string) { return 'foo'; }
function bar(v: string) { return 0; }

const callable: typeof foo | typeof bar = function() {} as any;

// Passes type check, presumably because the parameter lists match exactly (even though they have different return types).
callable('a');
```

This example is a simplified case that I originally discovered while trying to describe the notion of "continuous numeric D3 scale functions", which I had tried to define as:

```
import { ScaleContinuousNumeric, ScaleTime } from 'd3-scale';

type ValidScale = ScaleContinuousNumeric<number, number> | ScaleTime<number, number>;

const s: ValidScale = function() {} as any;

// No good, the only valid overload for `domain` is the no-argument one, even though both interfaces have one that accepts a superset of `Array<number>`.
s.domain([ 0, 1 ]);
```

Is there a construct that would allow me to express this without having to write a simpler interface that both `ScaleContinuousNumeric` and `ScaleTime` are assignable to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is unintended behaviour that appears for versions of TypeScript up til 3.3 where it was fixed. It is also mentioned in [the changelog](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#typescript-33) for TypeScript 3.3:

> #### Improved behavior for calling union types
>
> In prior versions of TypeScript, unions of callable types could only be invoked if they had identical parameter lists.
>
> ...
>
> In TypeScript 3.3, this is no longer an error.