# Union type of two functions in Typescript

Tags: typescript, types

I have a situation where I have a type which is a union of two functions which have a literal value as the type of one of their arguments. Boiled down to a minimal example, it is essentially this:

```
type FetchMini = (id: number, representation: 'mini') => MiniUser;
type FetchFull = (id: number, representation: 'full') => FullUser;

function f(fetchUser: FetchMini | FetchFull) {
  fetchUser(2, 'mini');
  fetchUser(2, 'full');
}
```

Both of these calls fail the compiler with the message:

> Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'FetchMini | FetchFull' has no compatible call signatures.`

I *think* I understand the reason why this happens, (...I think) but what could I do about it?

Here's a similar question, however it got no answers: [Union of functions is not callable even with parameters that meet each function's constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41668764/union-of-functions-is-not-callable-even-with-parameters-that-meet-each-function)

Comment: Check this issue: [Call signatures of union types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7294)

Answer (score 23):

Your `fetchUser()` is essentially an overloaded function which accepts *both* `mini` and `full`, thus should be *intersection*-typed, rather than union.

```
type MiniUser = { name: string }
type FullUser = { firstName: string, lastName: string, age: number }

type FetchMini = (id: number, representation: 'mini') => MiniUser;
type FetchFull = (id: number, representation: 'full') => FullUser;
type FetchBoth = FetchMini&FetchFull

function f(fetchUser: FetchBoth) {
    fetchUser(2, 'mini');
    fetchUser(2, 'full');
}

function fetchBoth(id: number, representation: 'mini'): MiniUser
function fetchBoth(id: number, representation: 'full'): FullUser
function fetchBoth(id: number, representation: 'mini' | 'full') {
    if (representation==='mini')
        return { name: 'Mini' }
    if (representation==='full')
        return { firstName: 'Full', lastName: 'User', age: 20 }
}
f(fetchBoth)
```

[PlayGround](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20MiniUser%20%3D%20%7B%20name%3A%20string%20%7D%0D%0Atype%20FullUser%20%3D%20%7B%20firstName%3A%20string%2C%20lastName%3A%20string%2C%20age%3A%20number%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20FetchMini%20%3D%20(id%3A%20number%2C%20representation%3A%20'mini')%20%3D%3E%20MiniUser%3B%0D%0Atype%20FetchFull%20%3D%20(id%3A%20number%2C%20representation%3A%20'full')%20%3D%3E%20FullUser%3B%0D%0Atype%20FetchBoth%20%3D%20FetchMini%26FetchFull%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20f(fetchUser%3A%20FetchBoth)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20fetchUser(2%2C%20'mini')%3B%0D%0A%20%20fetchUser(2%2C%20'full')%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20fetchBoth(id%3A%20number%2C%20representation%3A%20'mini')%3A%20MiniUser%0D%0Afunction%20fetchBoth(id%3A%20number%2C%20representation%3A%20'full')%3A%20FullUser%0D%0Afunction%20fetchBoth(id%3A%20number%2C%20representation%3A%20'mini'%20%7C%20'full')%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(representation%3D%3D%3D'mini')%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%20name%3A%20'Mini'%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(representation%3D%3D%3D'full')%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%20firstName%3A%20'Full'%2C%20lastName%3A%20'User'%2C%20age%3A%2020%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Af(fetchBoth))

As a rule of thumb, when you declare a function that accepts args of *both* type A *and* B, the function should be *&*-typed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like the initial idea is a bit incorrect. You should decide on what behavior you'd like to achieve.

From what I can see, **f** accepts a function which is responsible for fetching a user. Depending on the provided function either **MiniUser** or **FullUser** will be returned. If my suggestion is right, than consider the following example:

```js
class MiniUser {
    name: string;

    constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class FullUser extends MiniUser {
    age: number;

    constructor(name: string, age: number) {
        super(name);
        this.age = age;
    }
}

function fetchMiniFn(id: number) {
    return new MiniUser("John");
}

function fetchFullFn(id: number) {
    return new FullUser("John", 22);
}

function f(fetchUser: (id: number) => MiniUser | FullUser) {
    let a = fetchUser(2);
    if (a instanceof FullUser) {
        console.log("Full User: " + a.name + ", " + a.age);
    }
    else {
        console.log("Mini User: " + a.name);
    }
}

// Call the function to fetch MiniUser
f(fetchMiniFn);

// Call the function to fetch FullUser
f(fetchFullFn);
```

If my initial suggestion is incorrect and you still want the function **f** to decide what kind of User must be fetched than you can transform the code above to:

```js
function fetch(id: number, representation: 'mini' | 'full') {
    if (representation == 'mini') {
        return new MiniUser("John");
    }
    else {
        return new FullUser("John", 22);
    }
}

type FetchUser = (id: number, representation: 'mini' | 'full') => MiniUser | FullUser;

function f(fetchUser: FetchUser) {
    // Call the function with MiniUser fetching
    let mini = <MiniUser>fetchUser(2, 'mini');
    console.log("Mini User: " + mini.name);

    // Call the function with FullUser fetching
    let full = <FullUser>fetchUser(2, 'full');
    console.log("Full User: " + full.name + ", " + full.age);
}

// Call function:
f(fetch);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in my case it doesn't help. The types MiniUser and FullUser aren't classes, but just plain old javascript objects, which means that runtime checks like `instanceof` can't work. Using `<MiniUser>` is also not great since you could get the type wrong, eg: `<FullUser>fetchUser(2, 'mini')`, so it kinda defeats the purpose of having the types in the first place.

Answer (score -2):

you can solve it easly with generic and extends ( work for me in typescript 2.7.2 )

```
type FetchMini = (id: number, representation: 'mini') => MiniUser;
type FetchFull = (id: number, representation: 'full') => FullUser;

function f <T extends FetchMini | FetchFull >(fetchUser: T) {

    fetchUser(2, 'mini');
    fetchUser(2, 'full');
}
```