# What are alternatives for lookup object of functions?

Tags: javascript, typescript

What are (nice, readable, scalable, performant) alternatives for this simplified pattern?

```
type Shape =
    { kind: "square", a: number } |
    { kind: "rect", a: number, b: number } |
    { kind: "circle", r: number }
let area = {
    "square": function (s) { return s.a * s.a; },
    "rect": function (s) { return s.a * s.b; },
    "circle": function (s) { return s.r * s.r * Math.PI; },
    calc(s: Shape) {
        return area[s.kind](s);
    }
}
area.calc({ kind: "square", a: 2 });
```

---

Update:

It seems that shapes trigger people "to OOP" this problem. In my eyes, it is overkill to use the OOP mechanics for a simple function selection. Here is another example

```
var printEntity = function (s) {
    return {
        "named": function (s) { return "&" + s.id + ";"; },
        "decimal": function (s) { return "&#" + s.id + ";"; },
        "hex": function (s) { return "&#x" + s.id + ";"; }
    }[s.kind](s);
};
printEntity({ kind: "named", id: "ndash" });
```

Comment: Subclass polymorphism?

Comment: `class Shape { ... } ` ... `class Square extends Shape {...}` ...

Comment: Extending a `Shape` class should be elastic enough.

Comment: Subclassing works, until you need to expand the shape in two different directions...

Comment: Actually one doesn't even need subclasses here, sub*typing* is enough. JS can do that even for multiple interfaces with its duck-typing approach.

Comment: `area.calc({ kind: "calc" })` - oops :-P

Comment: Maybe I should have used another example. You are all OOPing this problem. Using OOP mechanics for function selection, might be a bit of overhead, I think.

Comment: @mhchem I don't think there's anything wrong with your pattern, or much left to improve. Using a set of `class`es with the methods, or using a `switch` statement, are the obvious *alternatives* that you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `switch` statement or an `if-else` cascade would do the trick.

Advantage: [TypeScript exhaustive checks](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/discriminated-unions.html) work.

Surprising: This is not slower than the map pattern. Tested with http://jsben.ch/3SRWx in Chrome 62.

```
type Shape =
    { kind: "square", a: number } |
    { kind: "rect", a: number, b: number } |
    { kind: "circle", r: number }

function area(s: Shape): number {
    switch (s.kind) {
        case "square": return s.a * s.a;
        case "rect": return s.a * s.b;
        case "circle": return s.r * s.r * Math.PI;
    }
    // gives error if not all possible cases were handled above
    const _exhaustiveCheck: never = s;
    return 0;
}
area({ kind: "square", a: 2 });
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is with an object-oriented style using prototype linkage. I'll stick with class syntax for clarity.

*This is actually a quite different approach in technical terms, but provides the same kind of interface.*

The first thing we need is a base object that stores required data and defines the interface for all shapes. In this case, we want that all shapes can output their area, calculated from their internal data:

```
class Shape {

    /**
     * @param {object} data
     */
    constructor(data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    /**
     * Calculates the area of the shape. Should be implemented by
     * all extending classes.
     *
     * @abstract
     * @return {number|NaN}
     */
    calculateArea() { return NaN; }
}
```

Now we can create some *subclasses*, note that all 'implement' (*override* is the technically correct term) the `calculateArea` method:

```
class Square extends Shape {
    calculateArea() {
        return Math.pow(this.data.a, 2);
    }
}

class Rect extends Shape {
    calculateArea() {
        return this.data.a * this.data.b;
    }
}

class Circle extends Shape {
    calculateArea() {
        return Math.pow(this.data.r, 2) * Math.PI;
    }
}
```

We are now able to create new Shape-extending objects like this:

```
const square = new Square({ a: 1 });
const rect = new Rect({ a: 2, b: 3 });
const circle = new Circle({ r: 4 });
```

However, we still have to *know* what kind of shape we want to create. In order to combine the feature where we can just give an additional property `type` within given data with the object-oriented style, we need a builder factory. To keep things organized, let's define that factory as a static method of `Shape`:

```
class Shape {

    /**
     * Creates a new Shape extending class if a valid type is given,
     * otherwise creates and returns a new Shape base object.
     *
     * @param {object} data
     * @param {string} data.type
     * @return {Shape}
     */
    static create(data) {

        // It's not at all necessary to make this part anything
        // more complicated than a switch-statement. If you wish,
        // you could move this to a standalone factory function
        // as well.
        switch (data.type) {
            case 'square':
                return new Square(data);
            case 'rect':
                return new Rect(data);
            case 'circle':
                return new Circle(data);
            default:
                return new this(data);
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

We now have a uniform interface to create shapes:

```
const square = Shape.create({ type: 'square', a: 1 });
const rect   = Shape.create({ type: 'rect', a: 2, b: 3 });
const circle = Shape.create({ type: 'circle', r: 4 });
```

Last thing to do is have a simple way to calculate an area directly. This should be easy though:

```
// You might want this as global function, or as another static
// method of Shape. Whatever works for your codebase:

function calculateArea(data) {
    const shape = Shape.create(data);
    return shape.calculateArea();
}

// Here you have it:
calculateArea({ type: 'square', a: 4 }); // => 16
calculateArea({ type: 'rect', a: 2, b: 3 }); // => 6
calculateArea({ type: 'circle', r: 1 }); // 3.14159265359...
```

Comment: This static `create` method now only serves as an elaborate complication for the `area` function lookup - just what the OP did with his object literal…

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean. This approach scales easily to both more types of shapes and an extended common interface. I can't really see how that can be done without a structure similar to this. The `create` method is _at this point_ only there to facilitate some functionality for the `calculateArea` function, but one can imagine there being more helper functions that can also leverage `Shape.create` to reach out to a common interface method all the way from some raw data. Could you please explain?

Comment: I don't see how this approach scales *better* than the OPs approach - but at the same time it is much more verbose.

Comment: In my experience it is more robust, and scales better in that (among other things)

- It doesn't throw an error when an invalid type is given
- It allows for facilities for similar lookups to be defined on the same objects
- It allows for creating new types of shapes by defining exactly 1 new class.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is just fine as it is, except for two relatively minor issues:

- As Bergi noticed in the comments, `calc` is in the same scope - in `area` object -  as all area kinds, so it prevents you from having an area kind named `calc`.
- The compiler does not check that you have area calculation methods for all possible shape kinds with correct signatures

So I think it could be marginally improved like this:

```
// this type is not strictly necessary, but nice to have
// to enforce each member of the interface below to have proper 'kind' member
type WithKind<K extends string> = {[kind in K]: { kind: kind }} 

interface ShapeTypes extends WithKind<keyof ShapeTypes> {
    square: { kind: "square", a: number }
    rect: { kind: "rect", a: number, b: number }
    circle: {kind: "circle", r: number}
}

type Shape = ShapeTypes[keyof ShapeTypes];

let areaMethods: {[K in keyof ShapeTypes]: (s: ShapeTypes[K]) => number} = {
// the type of s is inferred to be a proper kind of shape here
    square: s => s.a * s.a,
    rect: s =>  s.a * s.b, 
    circle: s => s.r * s.r * Math.PI,
};

function calcShapeArea(s: Shape): number {
    // unfortunately this has to be two lines instead of just one
    // return areaMethods[s.kind](s)
    // because in typescript, a union of compatible function types is not callable
    // see also https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4122
    // see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41668764/union-of-functions-is-not-callable-even-with-parameters-that-meet-each-function
    // also, it does not compile and needs a type cast with --strictFunctionTypes
    const areaMethod: (s: Shape) => number = areaMethods[s.kind];
    return areaMethod(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ECMAScript 2015 introduced the [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

```
map = new Map([
    [9, "nine"],
    [0, "zero"],
    [2, "two"],
    ['a', "a"],
    [{}, "empty object"],
    [x => x*x, "function"],
    [1, "one"],
]);

for (const [key, value] of map) {
    console.log(`${key} -> ${value}`);
}
```

So the example could look like this.

```
function area(s) {
    return new Map([
        ["square", s => s.a * s.a],
        ["rect", s => s.a * s.b],
        ["circle", s => s.r * s.r * Math.PI]
    ]).get(s.kind)(s);
}
area({ kind: "square", a: 2 });
```

Issues (as of 2017): [Not supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Browser_compatibility) by all browsers. Not supported by TypeScript.